# How can I count how many times I get a result in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

Currently, I have the following graph database in neo4j, with hundreds of thousands of "customers" (so there's hundreds of thousands of this layout in my neo4j database).

[image: graph databse layout]

Currently, I am running the following query:

```
MATCH (m:Member)-[r:ACTIVITY{issue_d:"16-Jan"}]->(l:Loan)
MATCH (m)-[:ACTIVITY]->(p:Payments)
MATCH (m)-[:HISTORY]->(c:CreditHistory)
WHERE NOT p.total_pymnt=0
RETURN l.funded_amnt,
       p.total_pymnt,
      (l.funded_amnt)-(p.total_pymnt) AS amountowed,
       r.issue_d AS dateissued,
       l.installment AS monthlypayment,
       l.int_rate AS interestrate,
       c.dti AS debt
ORDER BY (l.funded_amnt)-(p.total_pymnt) DESC 
LIMIT 50000;
```

And I get results like the following (except only for january as the "dateissued")
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR8zU.png)

I want to count how many times I get that a monthlypayment is greater than 1000, but the count(x) query in cypher only works to count things related to a single node, not across nodes. How can I count across all my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNT` *is* for counting things "across nodes".

This simple query should give you a count of the number of `l.installment` values > 1000:

```
MATCH (l:Loan)
WHERE l.installment > 1000
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

Comment: What does the * in COUNT(*) signify? (I'm just starting out with neo4j)

Comment: In this case, it means "count the number of result rows". But you should read up on [aggregation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-aggregation) to understand what happens in other situations when there are "key values".

Answer (score 0):

cybersam's answer is right, you may do it this way too:

```
MATCH (l:Loan)
WHERE l.installment > 1000
RETURN COUNT(l);
```

Since you are searching for `l.installment>1000` then just return the number of `l` which satisfy that condition.